# Aqua Resizer Function Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know if I accidentally messed with something, but for some reason when I visit my screenshot pages, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function aq_resize() in /single-screenshots.php on line 36

The code on that page is this:

```
<?php
                    // BEGIN SCREENSHOTS GALLERY
                    $attachment_args = array(
                         'post_type' => 'attachment',
                         'numberposts' => -1,          // one attachement image per post
                         'post_status' => null,
                         'post_parent' =>$post->ID,
                         'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
                    );
                    $attachments = get_posts($attachment_args);
                    if ($attachments) {
                      foreach($attachments as $gall_image )                                                                 
                      {
                        $att_img =  wp_get_attachment_url( $gall_image->ID);
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="'.$att_img.'" title="'.$gall_image->post_title.'">';
                        echo  '<img src="'. aq_resize($att_img, 140, 100, true) .'" alt=""/>';
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                      }
                    }

                    ?>
```

I'm not proficient in PHP so I have no clue what might have caused this? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `include 'aq_resizer.php'` before calling the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: It can't find the function `aq_resize()`.

Insure that [`aq_resizer.php`](https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer/blob/master/aq_resizer.php) is included in your code.

Read up on [how to use](https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer#how-to-use) Aqua-Resizer.

Comment: It is. The error completely says Fatal error: Call to undefined function aq_resize() in /home/user/botkai.com/wp-content/themes/leetpress/single-screenshots.php on line 36

I have the script uploaded to home/user/botkai.com/wp-content/themes/leetpress/includes.

Alright, I'll try that.

Comment: Yeah,  I added the code to my functions.php file and now it works.

Weird how it was working a few days ago. Again, maybe I deleted it and didn't notice. Thank you!